# Improve performance for computing Weighted Jaccard in a large matrix

Tags: r, performance, similarity, doparallel, parallel-foreach

R input: a matrix (measures x samples) (2291 x 265) (matrix [i,j]=a value between 0 and 1)

Output: a simmetric similarity matrix of the weighted jaccard computed between all the pairs of samples

Problem: find the fastest way to produce the output. I found a good way using "doParallel" and "foreach" but it is not enough because it is still too slow. I didn't find any package with a function able to compute the weighted jaccard but maybe I missed it. Anyway you can reply with the solution and the method that you like. Thanks to everyone will answer.
This is my script for now:

```
rm(list=ls())

#Load libraries ----
require(doParallel)
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
require(doMPI)
#Imported data ----
dim(input_m) #2291 x 265

#Set clusters ----
no_cores <- 3
cl <- makeCluster(as.integer(no_cores))
registerDoParallel(cl)

#I build all the combinations of the pairs of samples ----
samples=seq(1:ncol(input_m))
combs<-as.matrix(expand.grid(samples,samples))
combs<-unique(t(parApply(cl=cl, combs, 1, sort)))

#Prepare the resulting matrix ----
res_m <- matrix(ncol = ncol(input_m), nrow = ncol(input_m))
rownames(res_m)=colnames(input_m)
colnames(res_m)=colnames(input_m)

#Compute Weighted Jaccard similarity btw all pairs of samples ----
sim_m=foreach(s = 1:nrow(combs), .combine=rbind, .noexport=c("pair","num","den"), .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
    pair=input_m[,c(combs[s,1],combs[s,2])]
    num=sum(apply(pair,1,min))
    den=sum(apply(pair,1,max))
    return(c(combs[s,1],combs[s,2],num/den))
}

#Fill the prepared matrix with the results in sim_m
for (k in 1:nrow(sim_m)){
    sim=sim_m[k,3]
    idx1=sim_m[k,1]
    idx2=sim_m[k,2]
    res_m[idx1,idx2]=sim
    res_m[idx2,idx1]=sim
}

#Stop clusters
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You might take a look at the `proxy` package. I know it has a method for Jaccard, but am not sure about the weighted aspect. Probably worth checking out anyway.

Comment: @lmo the proxy package does not have the WJ implemented. It allows to define a custom function but then it wouldn't change the performances because it would depend again by my script. However, thanks for the answer, any feedback is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your answer and @HenrikB comments I managed to write a faster approach:

```
## simulate data
nr <- 2291; nc <- 265
set.seed(420)
input_m <- matrix(rnorm(nr * nc), nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
input_m[1:5, 1:5]
#             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
# [1,] -0.76774389  1.2623614  2.44166184 -1.86900934  1.61130129
# [2,] -1.44513238 -0.5469383 -0.31919480 -0.03155421  0.09293325
# [3,] -0.71767075 -0.2753542  2.28792301  0.41545393 -0.47370802
# [4,]  0.06410398  1.4956864  0.06859527  2.19689076 -0.96428109
# [5,] -1.85365878  0.1609678 -0.52191522 -0.79557319 -0.33021108

jaccardLuke <- function(input_m) {
  res_m = outer(1:ncol(input_m), 1:ncol(input_m) ,
                FUN = Vectorize(function(r,c) {
                  require(matrixStats)
                  sum(rowMins(input_m[,c(r,c)]))/sum(rowMaxs(input_m[,c(r,c)]))
                  })
                )
  rownames(res_m) = colnames(input_m)
  colnames(res_m) = colnames(input_m)
  res_m
}

jaccardHenrikB <- function(input_m) {
  require(matrixStats)
  res_m = outer(1:ncol(input_m), 1:ncol(input_m) ,
                FUN = Vectorize(function(r, r2) {
                  x <- rowRanges(input_m, cols = c(r, r2))
                  s <- colSums(x)
                  s[1] / s[2]
                })
  )
  rownames(res_m) = colnames(input_m)
  colnames(res_m) = colnames(input_m)
  res_m
}
```

My function:

```
jaccardMinem <- function(input_m) {
  require(data.table)
  require(matrixStats)

  samples <- 1:ncol(input_m)
  comb <- CJ(samples, samples)
  comb[, i := .I]
  comb <- melt(comb, 'i')
  setorder(comb, value)
  v2 <- paste0("V", 1:2)
  comb[, variable2 := v2 , keyby = i]
  comb2 <- dcast(comb, i ~ variable2, value.var = 'value')
  combUnique <- unique(comb2, by = c('V1', 'V2'))

  XX <- apply(combUnique[, -'i'], 1, function(x) {
    x2 <- rowRanges(input_m, cols = x)
    s <- colSums2(x2)
    s[1] / s[2]
  })

  set(combUnique, j = 'xx', value = XX)
  rez2 <- merge(comb2, combUnique[, -'i'], by = c('V1', 'V2'), all.x = T)
  setorder(rez2, i)
  rez2 <- array(rez2$xx, dim = rep(ncol(input_m), 2))
  rownames(rez2) <- colnames(input_m)
  colnames(rez2) <- colnames(input_m)
  rez2
}
```

Test if all equal:

```
all.equal(jaccardLuke(input_m), jaccardHenrikB(input_m))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(jaccardLuke(input_m), jaccardMinem(input_m))
# [1] TRUE
```

benchmarking:

```
system.time(jaccardLuke(input_m)) # 6.05 sek
system.time(jaccardHenrikB(input_m)) # 2.75 sek
system.time(jaccardMinem(input_m)) # 1.74 sek

## for larger data:
nr <- 5000; nc <- 500
set.seed(420)
input_m <- matrix(rnorm(nr * nc), nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
system.time(jaccardLuke(input_m)) # 41.55 sek
system.time(jaccardHenrikB(input_m)) # 19.87 sek
system.time(jaccardMinem(input_m)) # 11.17 sek
```

the main difference is that I firstly calculate unique index combinations for which we need to calculate the values

Comment: Wow, this is a solution that I couldn't imagine. Thanks for the answer and for also having improved my way to code in R.

Comment: Wow, I tested this against another two implementations of the code and it comes out the fastest. Thanks for your outstanding contribution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a very good solution that replaces all the original code and solves the problem in few lines of code.

```
rm(list=ls())
load("data.rda")
# dim(input_m) 2291 x 265
res_m=outer(1:ncol(input_m), 1:ncol(input_m) , FUN=Vectorize(function(r,c){
 require(matrixStats);
 sum(rowMins(input_m[,c(r,c)]))/sum(rowMaxs(input_m[,c(r,c)]))}))
rownames(res_m)=colnames(input_m)
colnames(res_m)=colnames(input_m)
```

Comment: 1. Instead of `rowMins(input_m[,c(r,c)])` use `rowMins(input_m, cols = c(r,c))`, and analogously for the rowMaxs().  That will do matrix subsetting internally and without having to create a copy; that is more efficient (speed and memory).  2. Use `library(matrixStats)` - you very rarely want `require()`.

Comment: Yet a further improvement is to calculate (min, max) in one go using `r <- rowRanges(input_m, cols = c(r,c))`. Then do `s <- colSums(r)` and return `s[1] / s[2]`.   ... and move `library(matrixStats)` outside of the `outer()` call to avoid calling it over and over.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; together with the answer of @minem you solved completely my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a finished version that will run for you because I'm not entirely sure what the input looks like and what the desired output should be. However, I do have some hints to speed up your code significantly.

**Step 1**

Your biggest hog is this piece of code

```
samples=seq(1:ncol(input_m))
combs<-as.matrix(expand.grid(samples,samples))
combs<-unique(t(parApply(cl=cl, combs, 1, sort)))
```

`expand.grid` is slow, `sort` is slow etc. etc. Incidentally, I've had the same problem (computing all pairwise products of all column in a matrix). You can access the function as `pairwise_combination_indices` in the `MESS` package (and you need the github version):

```
devtools::install_github("ekstroem/MESS")
```

Now look at this speed gain. `f()` corresponds to your three lines above

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(100), MESS::pairwise_combination_indices(100, self=TRUE))
Unit: microseconds
                                                 expr        min          lq
                                               f(100) 355670.517 386745.3550
 MESS::pairwise_combination_indices(100, self = TRUE)     31.006     44.3855
        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 414465.6852 409732.726 427356.848 575404.135   100   b
     85.7078     65.962     84.804    679.408   100  a
```

Now you need to compute the matrix of indices for 265 columns and not just 100 so the speed gain should be even larger. No amount of cores should be able to compete with that, so replace your three lines with

```
combs <- MESS::pairwise_combination_indices(ncols(input_m), self=TRUE)
```

**Step 2**

Your last loop should be vectorized and you can get away with (not tested)

```
res_m[cbind(sim_m[k,1], sim_m[k,2])] = sim_m[k,3]
res_m[cbind(sim_m[k,2], sim_m[k,1])] = sim_m[k,3]
```

Try these and see if it helps?

The Weighted Jaccard similarity btw all pairs could probably be computed really quickly in Rcpp.